# Timer Jobs auto provisioning?

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I want to create a timer job that will be on all of SharePoint's web applications.

It's not a problem - but I'm thinking of the situation when a new web application is created.

Will my timer job be automatically provisioned on that web application as well?

If not, How can I create a timer job that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about in the way you construct your Feature receiver. Simply create a Web Application scoped feature, which is automatically activated (set this in VS already in the Properties window). In this you would put something like that:

```
SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;

//Add code to check whether it is already added and Remove it 1st.
DeleteJob(webApp.JobDefinitions);

MyJobDefinition myJob = new MyJobDefinition(webApp);

//set schedule and other properties and then run Update 
myJob.Update();
```

Which constructor you choose is important, because beyond the WebApplication you would also have to consider "where" (on which server it runs - Central Admin by default, or specifically Front Ends..etc., i believe this examples would help http://www.martinhatch.com/2009/08/sharepoint-timer-jobs-and-multiple.html).

Not sure if you've gone through this article, as a comprehensive guide
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/a-complete-guide-to-writing-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-2010/